# Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found in /home/virtu182/public_html/login.php on line 3

Tags: php

So, just some hindsight, I have tried `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');` as well as `App::import('AppController', 'Controller');` and then it just gives me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /home/virtu182/public_html/login.php on line 5.

This is not a code I personally have wrote, but I can't find a solution. Here's the original code so you guys can take a look and see what the heck may be wrong:

```
<?php

class LoginController extends AppController{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->access = "guest";
        $this->handleAccess();
        $mysidia = Registry::get("mysidia");

        if($mysidia->input->post("submit")){
            if(!$mysidia->input->post("username") or !$mysidia->input->post("password")) throw new LoginException("fail_blank");
            else{
                $validator = new UserValidator($mysidia->user, array("username" => $mysidia->input->post("username"), "password" => $mysidia->input->post("password")));
                $validator->validate("username");
                $validator->validate("password");

                if(!$validator->triggererror()){
                    $mysidia->user->login($mysidia->input->post("username"));
                    if($mybbenabled == 1) $mysidia->user->loginforum();
                    $mysidia->session->terminate("clientip");
                }
                else throw new LoginException("fail_details");       
            }
            return;
        }       
        $mysidia->session->assign("clientip", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->access = "member";
        $this->handleAccess();
        $mysidia = Registry::get("mysidia");
        $mysidia->user->logout();       
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: is this from `login.php`? typically you should name the class exactly the same as the file otherwise you risk autoloaders not finding it, this includes casing.

Comment: Please share and mark line 5 of `login.php`

Comment: What's this funny thing `?>` ? I think I used that once a long time ago, but I didn't like it so I never used it again.

Comment: @NicoHaase line 5 is `public function __construct(){`
@ArtisticPhoenix After I do that, I get `Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found in /home/virtu182/public_html/login.php on line 3`

Comment: And where is that class `AppController`? In the same namespace? In the same folder? Is it loaded using an autoloader?

Comment: Next: what is `App::uses`? Please add all answers to the question, not to the comment section!